# Styling issue on upvoted comments by diamond moderators

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, design

OK I know this is minor, but I noticed that the upvote number on question comments isn't positioned correctly. Note the `2` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33263918/1663001) is raised a few pixels:

[image: Diamond mod picture]

If you remove the diamond the comment aligns correctly. Does this mean mod comments are ever so slightly more important than those from us mere mortals?!

PS This doesn't appear to be the case for [comments on answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670631/does-the-order-of-classes-listed-on-an-item-affect-the-css/15672815#comment54283695_15672815).

PPS Forgot that the picture should have a hand drawn circle on it...

Comment: "Does this mean..." Yes.

Comment: @BoltClock I should have expected that from you!

Comment: I wasn't expecting that particular comment of mine to wind up here, let alone for this reason :^)

Comment: @BoltClock No one expects DavidG's inquisition.

Comment: So does the extra spacing only occur for _single-line comments_ by diamond mods?  As far as I can see, [BoltClock's second comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308513/styling-issue-on-upvoted-comments-by-diamond-moderators#comment261261_308513) doesn't exhibit this behavior.  It looks more like the diamond makes the line of text larger than normal, and the number is aligned to the now heightened line of text.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: Yes, that is what appears to be happening.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: (Wow I've said yes a lot of times in the past hour.)

Comment: The solution to this bug is obvious. Remove @BoltClock's mod diamond...

Comment: @Bob: [\[status-completed\]](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eSRSK.png)

Comment: @BoltClock not good enough. I think this calls for account deletion...

Comment: Setting `line-height` to `1.1` or `1` on `.mod-flair` will fix this.

Comment: The problem is not that the 2 is raised, but that the text is lowered, if you look carefully. It's because the Unicode diamond is ever so slightly larger in height than regular characters, so pushes any text it's in with out of line. You see the same issue in multi-line mod comments, where the line gap between the first two lines is greater than any other comment, and greater than subsequent lines.

Comment: We haven't fixed the Jon Skeet bug yet where complete characters get lost (see [any answer by Jon](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2550935/480982)) but we start tracking pixel bugs already? Wow!

Comment: I wish to thank the two first commenters for providing a live example of the issue, without us having to dig for a post where it happens.

Comment: Those zero-width-joiners seem to have a 2px height after all!

Comment: The diamond icon is rendered using a larger font size which increases the overall line height of the entire comment. If they stick with regular font size then the diamond icon appears smaller and you don't get to notice it. See http://i.stack.imgur.com/uWGgE.png

Comment: @SalmanA I wish I could downvote your comment for having a red circle that isn't drawn by hand :(

Comment: There are indeed "styling issues" with some moderators' comments… not like they could be corrected using some CSS…

Comment: How did you even notice that? Is your screen set at 640 x 480?

Comment: @JoeMalpass Just good eyes I guess, working on a small 1680x1050 monitor where I am right now - really need to get a bigger screen...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. I have fixed the issue using [Ilmari Karonen's suggested CSS change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308596/2420979). It will be live in the next built (meta: > `rev 2015.10.23.3782`, prod: > `rev 2015.10.23.2901`). Cheers!

Comment: I still think you should've just deleted BoltClock's account instead.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a CSS fix (as suggested by TylerH [in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308513/styling-issue-on-upvoted-comments-by-diamond-moderators/308596#comment261301_308513)):

```css
.mod-flair { line-height: 1 }
```

As usual, I'll add this to the next release of [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch), if SE doesn't get around to fixing the issue first.

Comment: Seems to work in both mobile and regular views. Checking into ramifications of this now.